# Remove UIBarButtonItem image

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` that I originally change the background image to. But I would like to be able to change the same `UIBarButtonItem` back to a default looking one (specifically a done button). Then again back to the way it was prior to (that shouldn't be a problem).

Here is how I change the appearance at first:

```
 [menuButton setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Then back I was trying things like:

```
menuButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleDone;
menuButton.title = @"Done";

//the above didn't do anything, so I tried to make my own image to
//replace the first image. But below did't do anything either.

[menuButton setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"doneButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setBackgroundImage:...` instead of `setBackButtonBackgroundImage:...`, you're only setting the appearance of *back buttons* (in navigation bars).

Comment: If you can add to your answer: `[menuButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];` for future on lookers, you've got it perfect.